# How to add round radius text inside clock at specific timing?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, time

I have build a clock using css and html with the help other's code available on the internet. I want to show text in an arc shape between specific timings. See the attached image, I want to show specific text during a time frame. Planning to write up in reactjs.

7 PM - 9 PM  :  'Home Work' in Light Blue Background color
9 PM - 10:30 PM  :  'TV Time' in Light Green Background color
10:30 PM - 6:00 AM  : 'Bed Time' in Light Red Color.

These timings are not fixed, everyday during different time, I want to load different text with background color.

What I have so far is this. Any help is appreciated here.

[image]

```js
var dialLines = document.getElementsByClassName('diallines');
var clockEl = document.getElementsByClassName('clock')[0];

for (var i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
  clockEl.innerHTML += "<div class='diallines'></div>";
  dialLines[i].style.transform = "rotate(" + 6 * i + "deg)";
}

function clock() {
  var weekday = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = d.getMinutes(),
    s = d.getSeconds(),
    date = d.getDate(),
    month = d.getMonth() + 1,
    year = d.getFullYear(),

    hDeg = h * 30 + m * (360 / 720),
    mDeg = m * 6 + s * (360 / 3600),
    sDeg = s * 6,

    hEl = document.querySelector('.hour-hand'),
    mEl = document.querySelector('.minute-hand'),
    sEl = document.querySelector('.second-hand'),
    dateEl = document.querySelector('.date'),
    dayEl = document.querySelector('.day');

  var day = weekday[d.getDay()];

  if (month < 9) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }

  hEl.style.transform = "rotate(" + hDeg + "deg)";
  mEl.style.transform = "rotate(" + mDeg + "deg)";
  sEl.style.transform = "rotate(" + sDeg + "deg)";
  // dateEl.innerHTML = date+"/"+month+"/"+year;
  // dayEl.innerHTML = day;
}

setInterval("clock()", 100);
```

```css
.clock {
  background: #ececec;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 8% auto 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 14px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2vw 4vw -1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dot {
  width: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px black;
}

.hour-hand {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 1.5vh;
  height: 17vh;
  background: #333;
  top: 33%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  left: 49.25%;
  /*   margin-left: -2px; */
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.minute-hand {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 1vh;
  height: 27vh;
  background: #666;
  top: 23.5vh;
  left: 49.5%;
  /*   margin-left: -2px; */
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.second-hand {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  width: 0.5vh;
  height: 34vh;
  background: gold;
  top: 16%;
  lefT: 49.75%;
  /*   margin-left: -1px; */
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

span {
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  position: absolute;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Poiret One';
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 4;
}

.h12 {
  top: 5vh;
  left: 46.5%;
  /*   margin-left: -9px; */
}

.h3 {
  top: 47vh;
  right: 5%;
}

.h6 {
  bottom: 5vh;
  left: 48%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.h9 {
  top: 47vh;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div>
    <div class="info date"></div>
    <div class="info day"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="minute-hand"></div>
    <div class="second-hand"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="h3">3</span>
    <span class="h6">6</span>
    <span class="h9">9</span>
    <span class="h12">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="diallines"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look here for how to make text follow a curve using SVG graphics https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/

Comment: You can use this for the text https://obss.github.io/react-curved-text/ and for the arc maybe use SVG http://xahlee.info/js/svg_circle_arc.html